# How to create a 2x1 table in R?

Tags: r

[image: Image of my code]

I am trying to make a table in R comparing the year (2008-2018) against the number of deaths from a specific disease in that year, so that I can create a line graph. I have tried to do this with a matrix, however since the lengths of the 2 variables TimePeriod (2008:2018) and DeathsOverTime are different, I cannot make a table. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I have now tried to make the table without the variables, inputting each value (number of deaths) manually, whereas before I had listed them as Deaths2008, Deaths2009 etc. The table comes up, however the name of the columns and rows are just letters!

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data? A screenshot would do as well.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: If you have `year` from 2008 to 2018 (11 distinct values), how do you expect your table to be only 2x1? Perhaps you can use something like `aggregate(dat$deaths, dat[,"year",drop=FALSE], FUN = sum)`.

Comment: What I meant was that I wanted one column of dates and 1 column of the number of deaths in each year (11 values each), I suppose this would be a 2x11 table?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question.

But I "think" that you are looking for something like the following? We'll first construct a dataframe object in R that is similar to the table I think you are trying to get to. We can do this by feeding in the two vectors of data (Years and Deaths) and naming them at the same time. Note that the rownames are just sequential numbers.  That is OK.

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2008:2018),
  YearlyDeaths = c(211, 261, 259, 251, 240, 275, 244, 276, 274, 332, 85)
)

mydataframe

   Year YearlyDeaths
1  2008          211
2  2009          261
3  2010          259
4  2011          251
5  2012          240
6  2013          275
7  2014          244
8  2015          276
9  2016          274
10 2017          332
11 2018           85
```

Then you can graph with different options.  The `type = "c"` option is what provides the line between the points.  We are first defining the plot with base R's plot command, and then adding lines on top with the lines command.

```
plot(
  mydataframe$Year,
  mydataframe$YearlyDeaths,
  ylab = "Yearly Deaths",
  xlab = "Year",
  main = "Yearly Deaths"
)
lines(mydataframe$Year, mydataframe$YearlyDeaths, type = "c")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for! Sorry for the confusing question,  I am new to R (I am a medical student using it for statistical analysis of patient data) Thank you so much :)

Comment: When answers are useful anywhere on StackExchange, you can upvote them.  As a new user, you probably can't choose the "best" answer to your question, but eventually you can.